# Bitmap.Save keep old PixelFormat

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, image-processing, jpeg, tiff

I am converting a bunch of TIFF images to JPEG with the following code. I am having an issue that the image sizes are growing exponentially on black and white images with a lot of black specks on them. I have found out that the image coming in(TIFF) is PixelFormat Format1bppIndexed, but then it always saves them to JPEG as Format24bppRgb. Is there a way to always keep the PixelFormat of the original image so this issue doesn't occur? The PixelFormat of the original image is not always the same, as the images are color, b&W, grayscale.

```
 public static string[] ConvertTiffToJpeg(string fileName)
        {
            using (Image imageFile = Image.FromFile(fileName))
            {
                var test = imageFile.PixelFormat;

                FrameDimension frameDimensions = new FrameDimension(
                    imageFile.FrameDimensionsList[0]);

                // Gets the number of pages from the tiff image (if multipage) 
                int frameNum = imageFile.GetFrameCount(frameDimensions);
                string[] jpegPaths = new string[frameNum];

                for (int frame = 0; frame < frameNum; frame++)
                {
                    // Selects one frame at a time and save as jpeg. 
                    imageFile.SelectActiveFrame(frameDimensions, frame);
                    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(imageFile))
                    {
                        jpegPaths[frame] = String.Format("{0}\\{1}{2}.jpg",
                            Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName),
                            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName),
                            frame);
                        bmp.Save(jpegPaths[frame], ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    }
                }

                return jpegPaths;
            }
    }
```

Comment: No, that's not possible. The JPEG format only supports 24 bit color or 8 bit grayscale images.

Comment: Well, sure, JPEG supports only one pixel format, 24bpp.  How well it can compress depends on how random the pixels are.  The more "flecky" the more space it needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .jpg files will be 24-bit color or 8-bit grayscale. You can use 8-bit grayscale for 1 bpp black and white tiff images and save some space, but it's not possible to use indexed color or 1 bit per pixel with .jpg files.

Depending on the image target app, you may be able to save the 1 bpp tiff images as .png or .gif image instead of .jpg. That should be about as small as the tiff file if it is saved with indexed color or with 1 bpp.